# How to catch errors when downloading a file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Im using `react-native-fs` to download files from a server and to read the local system. Everything works great, however Im having an issue where I don't know how to catch the failure when downloading a file.

For example, if the user lost network, how can I catch that? What I want is to show an alert message to the user, hide the download percentage message that I'm showing and delete the uncomplete download.

I have the following code, but the `catch` never runs:

```
const result = FS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: url,                   // URL to download file from
  toFile: `${CACHE_DIR}/${name}`, // Local filesystem path to save the file to
  background: false,        
  progressDivider: steps,
  begin: onBegin,
  progress: onProgress,
  readTimeout: 2 * MIN,
  connectionTimeout: 30 * SEC,
});

return result.promise
  .then(() => {
    this.index[name] = {
      name,
      path: `${CACHE_DIR}/${name}`,
      size: 0,
    };

    return this.index[name];
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error!', error);   // <-- This code never runs :(

    // Show and alert message to the user...

   // Hide downloading message

   // Delete incomplete download file
 });
```

For now I'm only focusing on Android, but later on I will move on to iOS. I wonder if the same issue happens on iOS as well or if is only on Android.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second callback of `then`

```js
return result.promise
  .then(() => {
    this.index[name] = {
      name,
      path: `${CACHE_DIR}/${name}`,
      size: 0,
    };

    return this.index[name];
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('error!', error);   // <-- This code never runs :(

    // Show and alert message to the user...

   // Hide downloading message

   // Delete incomplete download file
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While this works when there's no connection at all, it doesn't work when there's an active connection downloading a file and network get lost in the middle of the transaction :( At this point I think this is a problem with `react-native-fs`, I will look at the source code and see if I can find an answer.

Comment: Hey @Crysfel any look with this?